# User edited 'barely an answer' with perfectly complete answer

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, quality-improvement

Whilst going through the suggested edits queue, I encountered a surprising situation and I'm confused as to how to review this.

User A posted an answer without any context or explanation. Then User B comes along and decides to *completely* re-do the answer and adds all kinds of information and reasons why the problem in the question occurred and why the solution by User A is, in fact, correct.

The way I see it, this shouldn't have been an edit, but an additional answer of much higher quality.

I should probably just approve the edit, in order for the post to appear on the site, as it's clearly an improvement. However, User B is the one who deserves all credit for this answer and I don't think that answerers like User A should be rewarded for such an answer.

There's no way I can answer in the name of User B. Should I just 'approve' and stop feeling bad for User B? Or is there any way to get User B the credit he deserves, except up-voting his other posts, just for the sake of it?

[image: Review_screenshot]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> I should probably just approve the edit, in order for the post to appear on the site, as it's clearly an improvement.

Yep. Don't second-guess yourself. If you're certain the edit makes the answer better, approve it.

Consider that the alternative is you rejecting the edit, leaving a crappy answer to waste future readers' time *and* wasting the editor's time. Seems like a bit of a high cost for some abstract ideal, don't it?

Comment: Well their stated first thought was, "this shouldn't have been an edit, but an additional answer", so approving it *would* be second guessing themselves.

Comment: They can think that all they want. I think that. I'd still approve the edit, because I also think I am not the dictator of everyone else's time.

Comment: This is usually where "conflicts with author's intent" tends to come in. While the answer is the same answer, the additional information didn't come from the author and could have been posted as its own answer. Because the new information would be its own, valid, answer, there's no reason to edit it into someone else's.

Comment: At best, that's a "perfect vs. good" situation, @Draco18s - you're reviewing an edit that takes a barely-adequate answer and fleshes it out; you don't have control over what the editor has already done, or whether they'll ever come back to the site again. I agree that changing an answer to recommend an entirely different solution is something that should be done reluctantly, **but that's not what happened here:** the intent was preserved; the edit added information that supported it.

Comment: Holy shat batman. Finally! This is the answer I have been waiting for ages. Don't try to pry for reasons to reject the edit, try instead to look for reasons to not approve it: where it objectively makes the post worse.

Comment: @Draco18s "Conflict with author's intent" implies, that there is a conflict. I am sure, that original author didn't intend to write bad answer. As long as the editor elaborates on original, clearly incomplete answer (vs actually mixing in their own POW), there is no conflicting intent. Of course, the original author can always disagree with *anything* about the edit, but that is true for any edit, and they have means to both voice their disagreement and roll-back the offending edit. Unless the author has abandoned their SO account, in which case who cares?

Answer (score 10):

If you *really* can't bring yourself to approve the edit in good conscience, you could always post the edited version as a [community wiki answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki) instead.

Upvotes on community wiki answers will not give you any "undeserved" rep, and the box that normally shows your user card below the answer will instead say "community wiki".  Of course, votes on such answers will also not earn any rep for the author of the edit, but then, neither would votes on the answer they tried to edit.

To comply with the attribution requirements of the [Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) used on SO (and with SO's own [plagiarism policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)) you should include a note in the community wiki answer indicating the original author of the content.  This is most easily and effectively done by linking back to the suggested edit itself, e.g. something like this:

> *Note: This answer was [originally posted by <user X>](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17394538) as an edit to <user Y>'s answer.  As the content contributed by X seemed substantially different and contrary to Y's intent, I have instead posted it as a separate community wiki answer here so that both answers may be preserved and judged on their respective merits.*

However, as Shog9 notes, edits that simply turn a badly written answer into a well-written one without changing its core substance should usually just be approved.  The community wiki solution described here is better suited for situations where the edited content really diverges drastically from the original (i.e. the original answer says "do this" and the edited version says "don't do this, do that").