# My suggested edit was rejected, but the same thing got changed

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

A little while ago, I [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21478037). It got rejected and edited. However, the rejecter changed the *exact same thing* I suggested to be changed. Why did it happen like that?

Comment: Not entirely the same. The editor also formatted the unformatted code pieces in the post.

Comment: @Floern but the editor also changed what I changed. Isn't that what approve and edit is for?

Comment: Did you just remove the tag but not fix the unformatted code? The person who rejected and edited removed the same tag you did, but also formatted the code, and the message says that "This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed."

Comment: @Davidthethird Depends.. maybe they decided that your tag-only edit is not good enough and you should have fixed the code format too.

Comment: @DavyM that isn't a *critical* issue. It's a very small formatting issue. Incorrect tagging, however, is a bigger issue.

Comment: Tag edits are generally the lowest class of edit. If your edit doesnt correct the other issues plaguing the post, people are going to feel like you're wasting their time, and will reject and edit to send you that message.

Comment: @TinyGiant how is it a waste of time to approve a small but at least slightly helpful edit?

Comment: Because 3 people have to review it, and you were too lazy to correct the glaring problems(s) with the post.

Comment: @TinyGiant it's not a glaring problem to have a couple of lines that don't have code formatting. However, having a completely unrelated tag can be very confusing and problematic.

Comment: Note that SE wants to just improve the post. There is a unending number of edit reviewers anyways https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356840/792066

Comment: Also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265638/792066

Comment: @Braiam according to the first post, if an edit is helpful, it should be approved.

Comment: The second one is really not relevant.

Comment: It is absolutely a glaring problem. That you dont see it as a problem is also a problem. And no, your edit was not helpful. If you want to be helpful, doing as little as humanly possible is usually not a very good way to do that.

Comment: The point is that if you edit the post you should fix all issues with it, not just a single aspect. It causes your fellow users who curate the edit review queue more work. It's nice you want to help make stuff better, but please consider your fellow users when you do.

Comment: @TinyGiant it is *not* a huge problem. It's very easy to tell that the OP has code in that section. However, it is very misleading when there is an unrelated tag.

Comment: @Will then what is the purpose of "Approve and Edit"? If edits were always supposed to fix everything, then there would be no need for approve and edit.

Comment: You're wrong, and people are telling you that you're wrong and that's why your edit was rejected. Refusing to believe what people are telling you doesnt change anything.

Comment: The purpose of approve and edit is for when someone actually makes an effort to correct all the problems but misses one or two. Not when someone does as little as humanly possible and misses literally everything else.

Comment: @TinyGiant First of all, I can argue my opinion if I want to. Opinions matter. Second of all, there were only one or two extra things the editor did that I did not.

Comment: But you didnt make any attempt to fix all of the problems with the post. You fixed as little as you could, and are denying that the rest of the problems are even problems. The community is showing their disagreement with your assessment.

Comment: @TinyGiant I did attempt to fix all the problems, because in my opinion, a couple lines of unformatted code is not what I consider a problem. As I said, I can share my opinion that it is not that hard to read a tiny bit of unformatted code.

Comment: As I said, the community is showing their disagreement with your assessment, both in the rejection of your suggested edit, and in the comments here and voting on your question. You can either choose to take that under advisement, or continue doing what you're doing hoping for a different result.

Comment: @TinyGiant the *entire point* of a discussion question is for the community to voice their opinion. I am part of the community, so I can voice my opinion, and everyone else can too.

Comment: I have at no point said that you cannot voice your opinion. I've said repeatedly that your opinion is wrong, and have provided my reasoning for that. Just as you are allowed to state your opinion, I'm allowed to state mine.

Comment: What is the end goal of bringing this up?  Are you trying to understand the norms of the community better?  Or are you trying to convince others to change the way they do things?  Because I can't honestly see any purpose to asking why this happened, and then rejecting the reasoning when you are told why.

Comment: @fbueckert I want to know why, and I am discussing whether they are valid points or not.

Comment: You know why.  You've been told.  Multiple times.  You don't have to agree.  But until you hit 2K, you *do* have to abide by the community decisions.

Comment: @fbueckert that's the entire reason I brought this up on meta. I wanted to know if it is just that particular user who would have done that, or the entire community.

Comment: Why did you post this meta question? Are you going to listen to people for advice? Are you going to at least consider that you are wrong? Asking because this thread is going to be a waste of time if you are not open to suggestions.

Comment: @ModusTollens I have considered that I am wrong, and I am listening to advice, however I disagree with it. That is literally all I am saying.

Comment: *...because in my opinion, a couple lines of unformatted code is not what I consider a problem.* Why not? Why would you be against formatting code in posts?

Comment: @BSMP I'm not against it, I'm just not concerned about a tiny bit of unformatted code because it does not change the post enough to be worth an edit.

Comment: Note that accepting an answer doesn't mean it becomes the accepted community process.  Acceptance has no real meaning on Meta, so accepting an answer that you agree with feels more like sour grapes than anything else.

Comment: @fbueckert an accepted answer is one that helps the OP the most. That answer helped me the most.

Comment: @David I think fbueckert's point is more that since an accept is meaningless, here it feels like you trying to stick it to the community's accepted consensus more than anything else. Not a 'this is the right answer', but a 'I still disagree and I'll show it this way. Take that, meta!'.  Not saying that's what you intend it as (or that if it is, it's bad in and of itself). Just sayin'

Comment: @Patrice I guess I see what you're saying. I didn't mean that, but I found pnut's answer to be clearer and more helpful to me.

Comment: The community has thus far shown disagreement with the answer you think is "clearer and more helpful". While you may find it as such, it is contrary to community consensus.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your edit was rejected because someone with edit privileges decided to do so.  They (presumably) decided that your edit didn't fix everything possible with the post, and that more was required.  They then demonstrated what else needed to be done by making a larger edit.  That action will finish the voting, as their edit will override yours.

Learn from that.  That seems like a good faith effort to further improve the post, and provide some additional learning in the process.  If you don't want your edits to be rejected, make edits that, in good faith, improve the post to the best of your ability.  If they get rejected, read the reject reason, and apply the additional learning to subsequent efforts.  We don't expect perfection.  But we generally do expect more than the bare minimum.

Answer (score 5):

Regardless of what other meta posts suggest, the site is a growing and changing enterprise and if the comments and votes are anything to go by, community consensus says: We don't like trivial edits that leave other issues within a post. It's a way to game the system for rep points by making suggested edits without taking an interest in truly improving the site. Unfortunately some users engage in many of these edits without a care to actually improve the body of the post.

As mentioned in the comments by [Tiny Giant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4639281/tiny-giant):

> Tag edits are generally the lowest class of edit. If your edit doesnt correct the other issues plaguing the post, people are going to feel like you're wasting their time, and will reject and edit to send you that message.

Having said that:

Formatting  require => File['/var/lib/docker-latest' into code `require => File['/var/lib/docker-latest'` when the remainder of the code is formatted into blocks is a ball line call. It's a suggested edit that would be justifiably  edited and improved or rejected and improved.

Comment: *sigh* I feel like almost anything can be used to game the reputation system nowadays...

Comment: @Davidthethird don't take it out of context. I referred to people who habitually make these types of edits. I defended your edit as ball line. I'm not sure myself if I would have rejected or approved it. Sometimes it depends on what posts they've come across in the review queue. Think about? Please

Comment: I do understand what you mean and I can see why it would be a debatable case. It just kinda bugs me how many people want to take advantage of the reputation system.

Comment: @Davidthethird you, me and most of the people reading this. Unfortunately when someone does mean well, they can get caught in the cracks. But that's something we can live with. That's why we have meta. I don't think you did anything particularly bad in this case tbh. But I know myself when you get caught on the end of a batch of poor edits, it can make the reviewer stricter in attitude.

Comment: Is reputation farming such a rampant problem though? I don't remember reading about evidence showing that. I mean I could believe it, it is an "easy" way to get  to that magical 50 rep to be able to comment... But this site is largely mysterious to new users, it can just as easily be someone that is going to "fix" problems with a tag they happen to like and do it in all the wrong ways.

Comment: @Gimby It's by edits that I managed to get all of my sock puppet accounts voting privileges. (Yvette I'm kidding, don't suspend me)

Comment: @Gimby It doesn't really matter *why* people are making the edits.  Maybe some of them are making trivial edits because they want the 2 rep, maybe they're making them because they don't realize all of the costs that come with suggesting edits, maybe they think changes to non-core tags are actually more impactful than they are.  Frankly it's not worth guessing the motivation for the edits, all that matters is that they're not useful.  Personally I expect most trivial edits *aren't* motivated by rep.  That doesn't make them any more appropriate as edits though.

Answer (score -6):

An edit made by a user with 2,000 or more rep is not a reliable yardstick. Your argument behind "*how is it a waste of time to approve a small but at least slightly helpful edit?*" applies – essentially better some improvement, if not all, than none – because that edit was not going to the review queue and hence involve others.

However there were several other aspects to be improved: a tag forced into the Title; `docker` with a small `d` (three times), and `yaml` rather than YAML, for example. It would not be efficient to process each such adjustment as a separate suggested edit.

I fully agree with your "*Incorrect tagging, however, is a bigger issue*" but your case there is weakened when the tag [perl-packager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl-packager) has no Usage guide. That's like a joker that means whatever anyone wants it to.

The difference between what you suggested and what the editor changed is trivial and had I not been bothered to be thorough but inclined to make the change you suggested and add four backticks I would have Accepted and Edited rather than Rejected and Edited. Where a suggestion is clearly well intentioned a "Reject and Edit" should be an educational experience for the user making the suggestion and in this case the edit executed was not a good example for educational purposes. Accept and Edit (more than was edited) would have been the correct course of action because, yes, tags are important.